# JMeter listener log.info messages do not appear in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I wrote a JSR223 Listener that has log.info messages.  Why do these log.info messages not appear in the Jenkins Console Output?  I have BeanShell Assertions with log.info messages that will appear in the Jenkins Console Output.  I'm just curious why Listener log.info messages won't show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log` is writing to jmeter log which isn't display in Jenkins

You can write to output strem using `OUT` as:

```
 OUT.println("Hello Jenkins");
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it.  I had print("stuff") but not OUT.println().  Appreciate the help